# C++: Wrong Destructor Called

Tags: c++, destructor

`Projectile` is a subclass of `Node`.
I want the `Projectile` destructor to be called.

Note: In the real-life scenario, I have a list of `Node*` that are `Projectile`, `Player` or `Enemy`, each with their own destructor.

`Node` does not have a specified destructor in the `.h file` (I assume it uses the default one.)

```
    Node* p = new Projectile();
    delete(p); //Projectile destructor is never called
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use virtual destructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Comment: Do you mean that `Projectile` inherits from `Node` (if so, `super class` is the wrong term there to relate `Projectile` to `Node`)?

Comment: A default destructor is not virtual. If it isn't already, turn up the compiler warning level (-Wall should be enough for this in g++) and you'll see the compiler telling you that what you've written isn't going to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it seems pretty clear from your question that `Projectile` is a **subclass** of `Node` (see [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Subclasses_and_superclasses)).

If you have a class like `Node` that is built for subclassing, then you should ensure that its destructor is virtual:

```
class Node
{
...
    virtual ~Node();
};
```

This will cause the compiler to call the appropriate class`s destructor when you`delete` a pointer to the superclass.

(A different question is whether it should be pure virtual.)

Comment: You know, I've never tried a pure virtual destructor. That's going in the queue for experimenting tomorrow.

Comment: Why aren't all functions always virtual? Is there an advantage to have them not virtual?

Comment: There are several reasons. One of them is that there is a runtime overhead associated with using them, and C++ philosophy is "pay only for the feature you're using". Bjarne Stroustrup has a book about these things; something like "The Design and Evolution of the C++ Language".

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the destructor of `Node` to be `virtual`, the default one (non-virtual) doesn't satisfy the needs here, i.e. the dynamic polymorphism won't work.

```
class Node {
public:
    virtual ~Node() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ is static type language, so from this statement `Node* p = new Projectile();` compiler sees p as an object of Node. While destructing p, it will call destructor of class `Node` only.

To overcome this scenario, `virtual` comes into the picture.

Code:

```
class Node {
  public:
    virtual ~Node() {
      //delete resources allocated in Node class
    }
};

class Projectile : public Node {
  public:
    ~Projectile() {
       //delete resources allocated in Projectile class
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Make your destructor in `Node` virtual.

```
class Node {
  // Stuff...
  virtual ~Node();
};
```

Not-So-Short answer:

When `Projectile` and likes of that inherit `Node`, data members and functions are inherited from the `Node`. The derived class can override or replace the actual function definition in the parent class. This overriding happens at either Compile time or at the run time, depending on weather the function in the base class is declared 'virtual'.

In case of non-virtual destructor, the destructor to be called is determined by the type of pointer. So even though the pointer variable `p` is pointing to an instance of `Projectile`, `delete(p)` would call the destructor defined in `Node`.

In case of virtual destructor, the destructor to be called is determined at run-time. So, regardless of the pointer type, the destructor that gets called will be the one that is defined in the object pointed by `p`.